# Swift. Передать url из маркера на другой контроллер

Tags: swift, карты

Я делаю приложение для просмотра IP-камер и хочу добавить камеры к карте, так что вы можете кликнуть на нужный маркер и пойти, чтобы увидеть нужные камеры. У меня есть карта и PlayerViewController, которые воспроизводят веб-камеры.

Сейчас каждый маркер передает только первый поток веб-камеры. Помогите мне. Как это сделать?

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var moscow: [(name: String, URLs:String, img:String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double)] =
    [("cam1", "http://example/1.m3u8", "1.jpg", 55.753989, 37.620235),
     ("cam2", "http://example/2.m3u8", "2.jpg", 55.741308, 37.653914),
     ("cam3","http://example/3.m3u8","3.jpg", 55.742468, 37.629292)]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var latitudes = moscow.map({ $0.latitude })
        var longitudes = moscow.map({ $0.longitude })
        var annotations = moscow.map({ $0.name })

        for i in 0...2 {
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudes[i], longitudes[i])
            let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.003, 0.003)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated:true)

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = coordinate
            annotation.title = annotations[i]
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        print(#function)
    }

    // Called when the annotation was added
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView?.animatesDrop = true
            pinView?.canShowCallout = true
            pinView?.isDraggable = true
            pinView?.pinColor = .purple

            let rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)
            pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as? UIView
        } else {
            pinView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pinView
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        print(#function)

        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTheMoon", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override  func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toTheMoon" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! PlayerViewController

            var urlll = moscow.map({ $0.URLs })

            for i in 0...2 {
                controller.webcamURL = urlll[i] // only first cam play
            }
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChange newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {
        if newState == MKAnnotationViewDragState.ending {
            let droppedAt = view.annotation?.coordinate
            print(droppedAt)
        } 
    }
}
```

**PlayerViewController**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class PlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    var webcamURL:  String!
    var webcamTitle: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = webcamTitle
        let url = URL(string: webcamURL)
        player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        player!.play()     
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.player!.pause()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        player = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по коду, должна 3 камера всегда открываться. Чтобы открывалась нужная камера, необходимо определять на какой маркер нажали и по нему передавать данные.

Comment: Я пытаюсь это сделать, но пока в голову ничего не приходит.